# MySQL Select Puzzle

Tags: mysql

I have a chrome extension that allows users with the extension to find other users on a particular website.  Every five minutes, each user that has the chrome extension installed will be logged in the `log` table and every user with them (whether or not they have the extension) will be logged in the `seen_log` table.

Here is an abbreviated view of the tables:

### Table for logging users who have the extension installed:

```
log
|-----------------------------------------------|
| id | timestamp | userid | username | location |
|-----------------------------------------------|
```

### Table for all users (both those who do and do not have the extension installed):

```
seen_log
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| id | ip_address | timestamp | userid | username | location | version |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

### Table that shows which users a user follows:

```
following
|------------------------------------------------|
| id | timestamp | root_userid | followed_userid |
|------------------------------------------------|
```

I need to come up with a mysql select statement that will do the following:

- Take a userid and get the set that it follows.
- From each of those users, get the location and the username.
- Finally, determine whether or not they are online (`timestamp > date_sub(utc_timestamp(), interval 5 minute) as online`) and whether or not they have the extension installed (i.e. if they exist in the `log` table)

In short, here is the expected structure:

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| followed_userid | followed_username | location | online | hasExtension |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I am stumped.  Could you give me some pointers?

Edit:

Specifically, here is one problem I am facing.  I need to join the list of followed userids with the latest tuples of `seen_log`.  Why does this not get me the most recent entries for each unique `userid` in the `seen_log` table?

```
select k.*, k.timestamp > date_sub(utc_timestamp(), interval 5 minute) as online
from (
    select MAX(id) as max_id, e.*
    from seen_log e
    group by userid
) k
where k.id=k.max_id
```

Comment: Learn about `JOIN` statements

Comment: Your question is a but confusing. Can't understand which table is for what. Also, this is non-normalized. Why is username being repeated in addition to userid?

Comment: @maythesource.com It is an extension that does not require logging in, and has really no way of validating the authenticity of requests. It would be very easy to change the post data and send false data currently. I left all of the raw data in so that I could back-track if anybody exploited this.  Also, things like username and even location ids and usernames are able to be changed.  I'm not dealing with much data, and I did not realize this would be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
select
    *,
    timestamp > date_sub(utc_timestamp(), interval 5 minute) as is_online,
    userid in (select userid from log) as is_registered
from seen_log a
join (
    select max(id) as max_id
    from seen_log
    group by userid
) b
on a.id=b.max_id
where userid in (select followed_userid from following where root_userid = /* user id */ )
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job

```
select
    fol.root_userid as root,
    root.username,
    root.location,
    fol.followed_userid as follower,
    follower.username,
    follower.location,
    case when follower.timestamp > date_sub(utc_timestamp(), interval 5 minute) then 'online'
    else 'offline' end as is_online,
    case when fol.followed_userid in (select id from log) then 'registered' 
    else 'guest' end as is_registered 
    from following fol
    join log root on (root.id=fol.root_userid) 
    join seen_log follower on (follower.id=fol.followed_userid)
    order by fol.root_userid;
```

Comment: Hmm. I'm not able to get that to work. Could you add in some indentation?

Comment: its pretty hard to write a select if i dont know model/dbs but i will try. the idea of this is that i start from table of followers(fol) then connects log table with root id so i can get her username and location, and the n i connect seen_log to get the username/location of follower  so the first 3 selected colums are roots id,username and location, other 3 are followers id,username and location and that other two are only tests of that if the user is online/registered .

Comment: i made a cosmetic changes,try it know,if you are getting some error ,paste it here